# Show column by max() other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, max

I have a database table with 3 columns: `id`, `number1`, `number2`.
`id` contains `1,2,3...n` and `number1`, `number2` contains regular int numbers.

I want to show in the result the id column which will show the max value from `number1*number2`.

I wrote this:

```
select id, max(number1*number2) from numbers;
```

But in the result it shows me the `id` and `number1*number2` columns.

I want to show only `id` in the result.

Comment: @Mureinik i saw that you edited what i wrote. sorry for that i am kind of new here. how do i do those bold characters for variables?

Comment: You can create codeblcoks inline by surrounding them with backticks, or on separate rows by indenting (at least) four spaces. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for the complete details

Comment: read it about 5 minutes ago and saw it. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an inner query to get the multiplication and then use the outer one to get the entire row:

```
SELECT id
FROM   mytable
WHERE  (number1 * number2) = (SELECT MAX(number1 * number2) FROM mytable)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like that:

```
select id
from numbers
order by number1*number2 desc
limit 1
```

Comment: This would work as long as the result of `number1*number2` is distinct. If two or more rows would have the same product, you'd miss all but one of them.

Comment: @Mureinik yes, probably I misunderstood question, but it looks like OP want single id, maybe I'm wrong